# How do I compare user input to a variable?

Tags: javascript, html

I don't know how to make this work. Does anyone know how to fix this? I have tried multiple different solutions, but they don't work

```js
function submit() {
  var user = "test";
  if (document.getElementById('#user').input = user) {
    //what I need help on
  }
}
function openForm() {
  document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "block";
}

function closeForm() {
  document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<button class="open-button" onclick="openForm()">Open Form</button>

<div class="form-popup" id="myForm">
  <form action="#" class="form-container">
    <h1>Login</h1>

    <label for="username"><b>username</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="username" id="username" name="username" required>
    <button type="submit" onclick="submit()" class="btn">Login</button>
    // And here
    <button type="button" class="btn cancel" onclick="closeForm()">Close</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: You can access the value of an input using `value` property of node. Eg. `document.getElementById('#user').value`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, where is user input element, that you mentioned in JavaScript, there is no  input with id user, only one input with id username exist, use that and hashtag is not used for ids in `document.getElementById`
replace

```
document.getElementById('#user')
```

to

```
document.getElementById('username') // use username and remove the hashtag (#)
```

Secondly, use value instead of input

```
document.getElementById('username').value
```

Returns the value (text) of the input element

Lastly, use `==` or `===` operators in statements not `=` in JavaScript.

Example

```
if (document.getElementById('username').value === user) { // Replaced = with ===
    //what I need help on
}
```

Full JavaScript Code

```
function submit() {
  var user = "test";
  if (document.getElementById('username').value === user) {
    //what I need help on
  }
}
function openForm() {
  document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "block";
}

function closeForm() {
  document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "none";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead

```
if(document.getElementById('#user').value == user)
```

I'd suggest you to store the input element in a variable first to dry your code ;)

Answer (score 0):

I see you got the wrong username id, try my code below:

```
function submit() {
    var user = "test";
    if (document.getElementById('#username').value == user) {
        //what I need help on
    }
}
```